# How to fix this error Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing, matrix, reshape

I have a problem with this line of code `bloop(rj,cj) = J1(i,j)`. I tried it a lot and changed the numbers, but the error remains.
The Error is **Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds**
`bloop(rj,cj) = J1(i,j)`.

I hope someone has a solution to this problem.

```
clc 
clear 
close all
J = imread('logo.jpg'); %discolored image
J1 = im2double(J); %convert image to bouble precise
[r,c] = size(J1); %find size of image
rc = r*c; %151874

%find A inverse
x = [17;121;171];
xT = x';
xxT = x*xT;
inv = pinv(xxT); %find inverse for singular or badly scaled
y = [17;122;114];
yxT = y*xT;
Ainv = yxT*inv;
B = Ainv;

%find color correction
%reshape matrix to 3xn
i = 0;
j = 0;
bloop=zeros(3,50625);
for rj = 1:3 %row
    i = i+1;
    for cj = 1:50625 %cols
        j = j+1;
        bloop(rj,cj) = J1(i,j);
    end
end
[w,t] = size(bloop);
bloop(:,:)
%I(r,c) = BJ(r,c)color correction equation
I = B*bloop;
```

Comment: Is your image 3x50625?

Comment: yes, its 3x50625

Comment: simply use reshape function to change its size

Answer (score 0):

Your j doesn't get reset to zero for each rj/i. Move the `j = 0` inside the i loop.

```matlab
clc 
clear 
close all
J = imread('logo.jpg'); %discolored image
J1 = im2double(J); %convert image to bouble precise
[r,c] = size(J1); %find size of image
rc = r*c; %151874

%find A inverse
x = [17;121;171];
xT = x';
xxT = x*xT;
inv = pinv(xxT); %find inverse for singular or badly scaled
y = [17;122;114];
yxT = y*xT;
Ainv = yxT*inv;
B = Ainv;

%find color correction
%reshape matrix to 3xn
i = 0;
bloop=zeros(3,50625);
for rj = 1:3 %row
    i = i+1;
    j = 0; 
    for cj = 1:50625 %cols
        j = j + 1;
        bloop(rj,cj) = J1(i,j);
    end
end
[w,t] = size(bloop);
bloop(:,:)
%I(r,c) = BJ(r,c)color correction equation
I = B*bloop;
```